# sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command error

Tags: shell, sed

```
sed -i “s:export BINDIR ?= /usr/local/bin/:export BINDIR ?= /usr/sbin:g” Makefile
```

I am getting the below error on running above command on ubuntu 14.04. Can please somebody help me with the issue ?

Error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `�'

Comment: your double qoutes looks odd. It's probably some unicode char, can you see the difference between `“` and  `"`? You've probably copy&pasted it from somewhere, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sed -i 's:export BINDIR ?= /usr/local/bin/:export BINDIR ?= /usr/sbin:g' Makefile
```

Comment: Double quotes (`"`) are here no problem but you used (`“`) and escaped them.

Comment: oh sorry, I put the wrong code. I was getting the error without escaping the (`"`). I edited above code.

Comment: Use single or double quotes. This are **no** double quotes: `“`